# IDictionary Controller and Interface C#

Tags: c#

I have an object coming back with multiple lists that looks like this:

[image]

This is for a PUT route so I want to just sent it back with new value's. Keys can't change. I have worked with IEnumerables so most of the method logic is still geared towards that but before I even write that, I am trying to just make sure the dictionaries are getting to the method in my service and I haven't gotten there yet.

I can't seem to get the syntax right when returning this in the MVC. I keep getting this error in the controller:

[image: error]

I have tried to await the products in the retObj but I just get an endless processing wheel and nothing happens. Any help on how to set this up?

**Controller**

```
     [HttpPost("{operatorId}/products/{operatorRegionId?}")]
    [Authorize(Permissions.Admin.Operators.Update)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PostOperatorPrices([FromRoute] string operatorId, [FromRoute] string operatorRegionId, [FromBody]  Task<IDictionary<string, List<OperatorProductViewModel>>> products)
    {
        var retObj = await _productService.AddOperatorProductPrices(operatorId, operatorRegionId, products, await _accountService.GetUserIdFromPrincipal(User));
        return new OkObjectResult(this._respService.packageResponse(retObj));
    }
```

**Interface in Service**

```
    Task<IDictionary<string, List<OperatorProductViewModel>>> AddOperatorProductPrices(string operatorId, string regionId, IDictionary<string, List<OperatorProductViewModel>> products, string userId);
```

**Method**

```
public async Task<IDictionary<string, List<OperatorProductViewModel>>> AddOperatorProductPrices(string operatorId, string regionId, IDictionary<string, List<OperatorProductViewModel>> products, string userId)
    {
        var retDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<OperatorProductViewModel>>();
      //  List<string> productIds = new List<string>();
        foreach(var product in products)
        {
        //     OperatorRegionProductPrice myPrice = null;
        //     if (product.Id != null && product.Id != "")
        //     {
        //         myPrice = await _operatorRegionProductPriceRepo
        //             .GetSingleAsync(oppr => oppr.Id == product.Id);
        //     }

        //   //  if (myPrice == null) {
        //         myPrice = new OperatorRegionProductPrice{
        //             Id = _idService.GetIdString(),
        //             EffectiveDate = 
        //             new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local)
        //              .AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(product.EffectiveDate)),
        //             IsTaxable = product.isTaxable,
        //             TenantId = TenantId,
        //             OperatorId = operatorId,
        //             RegionId = regionId,
        //             OperatorPrice = product.Price.GetValueOrDefault(),
        //             OperatorCost = product.Cost.GetValueOrDefault(),
        //             UpdateUserId = userId,
        //             CreateUserId = userId,
        //             ItemId = product.ProductId,
        //         };
            //     _operatorRegionProductPriceRepo.Add(myPrice);
          
            
            // productIds.Add(myPrice.Id);
        }
    //    await DeleteOperatorProductPrices(operatorId, regionId, products);
        await _operatorRegionProductPriceRepo.CommitAsync();
        return retDictionary;
    }
```

Comment: Your `products` parameter in `PostOperatorPrices` is a task when it should be a dictionary. It's not clear why you've made it a task, or where it will be coming from... but either you need to change the parameter type, or await it and pass the result of that into the `AddOperatorProductPrices` method.

Comment: Posting images of technical information like sample data or error messages, instead of formatted text, is the fastest way I know to get your question downvoted and ignored.

Comment: @JonSkeet not sure why I thought it needed to be a Task, but you are right! Any thoughts on how to update the dictionaries within the method now?

Comment: @MambaForever Not gatekeeping (ie: I haven't and won't downvote this, and did read through the question to see if I could help). Actually this is the opposite: I passed on what I've observed **will** actually happen to help you get past those who do gatekeep.